# php download file slows

Tags: .htaccess, download, php

OK first off thanks for your time I wish I could give more than one point for this question.

Problem: I have some music files on my site (.mp3) and I am using a php file to increment a database to count the number of downloads and to point to the file to download. For some reason this method starts at 350kb/s then slowly drops to 5kb/s which then the file says it will take 11hrs to complete. BUT if I go directly to the .mp3 file my browser brings up a player and then I can right click and "save as" which works fine complete download in 3mins. (Yes both during the same time for those that are thinking it's my connection or ISP and its not my server either.)

So the only thing that I've been playing around with recently is the php.ini and the .htcaccess files.

So without further ado, the php file, php.ini, and the .htcaccess:

download.php

```
<?php

include("config.php");
include("opendb.php");

$filename = 'song_name';
$filedl = $filename . '.mp3';      

$query = "UPDATE songs SET song_download=song_download+1 WHERE song_linkname='$filename'";          
mysql_query($query);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filedl));
header('Content-type: audio/mp3');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filedl));
readfile('/music/' . $filename . '/' . $filedl);

include("closedb.php");
?>
```

php.ini

```
register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = off

expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 60
variables_order = "EGPCS"
extension_dir = ./
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
precision = 12
SMTP = relay-hosting.secureserver.net
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="


; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.MindCollar.com)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.MindCollar.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>
```

thanks for you time

Comment: What if you put `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');`instead of `header('Content-type: audio/mp3');`?

Answer (score 0):

what if you update your database  , then redirect user with

```
header('Location: path_to_MP3');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error:

```
$query = "UPDATE songs SET song_download=song_download+1 WHER song_linkname='$filename'";
```

mysql_query($query);

should be

```
$query = "UPDATE songs SET song_download=song_download+1 WHERE song_linkname='$filename'";
```

mysql_query($query);

apparently if fails but it is too late for you to see that the error has happened and download begins.

Also, since you are not doing anything with the DB anymore, move this line:

```
include("closedb.php");
```

above the headers. It is always safer this way

Comment: Thanks for the tip of the closedb. Sorry actually I changed the variables when I copied it over to stackoverflow... I wish that was the problem though...

Comment: it is not the variable, it is the SQL statement: should be WHERE not WHER

Comment: that's what I meant in the file it is WHERE, copying it over I typoed

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&param=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

use this .htaccess code